# How does scanner.next() works in java

Tags: java

I am trying to take input from STD in and printing it on the console. Below is the program. I am trying to print only three numbers. But My input is taking more than 3 numbers What am I doing wrong here?

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        String reg= "^-?(\\d+)$";
            int b[]= new int[3];
      Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
      for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
          if(sc.next().matches(reg)){
              b[i]= Integer.parseInt(sc.next());
          }

      }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(b));
      for(int c=0;c<b.length;c++){
          System.out.println(b[c]);
      }

    }

output:
------------------
20
30
40
50
60
70
[30, 50, 70]
30
50
70
```

Comment: what does `if(sc.next().matches(reg)){` supposed to do?

Comment: You're reading 6 numbers, 2 each time through your loop. 3 in your if check, and then another three in parseInt.

Comment: my intention was. If user types other than numbers. skip them. and take only numbers thats why I added sc.next().matches(reg).

Comment: @azurefrog piyush: Thanks for answers

Comment: read scanner class documentation

Answer (score 0):

You're moving to the next input each time you call `next()`. If you want to check and then save, you need to hold it in a variable:

```
  for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
      String input = sc.next();
      if(input.matches(reg)){
          b[i]= Integer.parseInt(input);
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out my quick fixed:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String reg= "^-?(\\d+)$";
            int b[]= new int[3];
      Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
      for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
          String tmp = sc.next();
          if(tmp.matches(reg)){
              b[i]= Integer.parseInt(tmp);
          }else{
             i--;
          }

      }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(b));
      for(int c=0;c<b.length;c++){
          System.out.println(b[c]);
      }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign your input to a temporary variable. Then recompile the program.
Hope this helps !